# Django Filter Query by Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm struggling getting the right query for my project. Here is an example or my model :

```
from django.db import models

class Pictures(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bild = models.FileField(upload_to='article_pictures/')
    articel = models.ForeignKey('articles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Articles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

how do I get the published artikles from the artikles class including the pictures (if there is one, or more)?

Thank you for your help

Comment: With respect to table design won't it be better if you define a many to many model. As one artikle (I am assuming article) can contain multiple images and one image can be used in multiple artikle.

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Comment: post your views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note**: models have *singular* names, so you should rename `Articles` to `Article` and `Pictures` to `Picture`.

The related `Picture`s of an article `article` can be obtained with:

```
my_article.picture_set.all()
```

this is a queryset that contains all the related pictures.

We can obtain the `Article`s that are publised, and then fetch the related `Picture`s in two extra queries with:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True).prefetch_related('picture_set')
```

So in a template you can then render it like:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {{ article.name }}
    {% for picture in article.picture_set.all %}
        {{ picture.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it worked!
Thank you so mutch for your help

also a big thanks to your note about my model classes, I am not much of an django user :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any exact query for this, but you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) to pre-load data from database. For example:

```
articles = Artikles.objects.filter(published=True).prefetch_related('pictures_set')

for article in articles:
     article.pictures_set.all()  # will not hit database
```

Answer (score 1):

All published articles:

```
Articles.objects.filter(published=True)
```

A single published Article(Example):

```
article = Articles.objects.filter(published=True).first()
# and it's pictures
for picture in article.pictures_set.all():
    print(picture)
```